# The keyword 'system' generates InternalParser with errors

Tags: java, grammar, keyword, xtext

When I add a keyword `system` to my grammar, the generated `InternalParser` shows errors, when the keyword is a java class. For Instance I use `system`, which is also used a class used in the following method.

```
public static final int System=98;     
public final boolean synpred196_InternalDummyParser() {
            state.backtracking++;
            int start = input.mark();
            try {
                synpred196_InternalFoStructuresParser_fragment(); // can never throw exception
            } catch (RecognitionException re) {
                System.err.println("impossible: "+re);
            }
            boolean success = !state.failed;
            input.rewind(start);
            state.backtracking--;
            state.failed=false;
            return success;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this. With **XText 2.6.2** was everything working fine, but I have this error using **XText 2.7.2**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to my mind is a post-processing step on the grammar that replaces System.err.println by some serious exception. Meanwhile you may want to file a ticket against Xtext.

Comment: There is no XText version 2.7.2 in eclipse bug tracker. I can choose 2.7.1. Would be ok, if I add the bug to 2.7.1?

Comment: Sure, just pick any version. If you state in the text that you use 2.7.2, it's convincing us that you do so.